# Is the ArcGIS Server JavaScript API free to use?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

The 2008 [blog post](http://blogs.esri.com/Dev/blogs/arcgisserver/archive/2008/07/08/The-ArcGIS-JavaScript-API-is-now-available-to-the-public.aspx) announcing the ArcGIS Server JS API says:

> Everyone can use the ArcGIS JavaScript API. There is no fee for using the ArcGIS JavaScript API or deploying an application built with it.

But Esri's [Web Mapping Pricing](http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/apis/pricing) page says "Contact us for pricing".

Which is correct?

Comment: The API is free - its the geoprocessing and geodatabase access you need behind the scenes that means you will require ArcGIS Server.

Comment: But if you're able to use someone else's ArcGIS Server, or omit it completely (by using Fusion Tables, GeoServer, etc), it's definitely free to use the APIs for a commercial application? Is there a reference to confirm this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It is free for the uses outlined in the top section in your "Web Mapping Pricing" link:

- Development and Evaluations
- Non-commercial external use
- Education(teaching purposes only)
- NGO or not-for-profit business
- When used in conjunction with ArcGIS for Server license
- When used in conjunction with ArcGIS Online Task Services totaling $4,000 per year or more

For commercial use, on a publicly accessible website, it is not free. That's when you need to contact sales for a quote.

**Edit**:  best source for this info as of December 2013 is https://developers.arcgis.com/en/terms/

Comment: Thanks. It might be an idea to amend the blog post?

Comment: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/6662/can-you-use-arcgis-online-base-maps-without-esri-software/6664#6664 similar question?

Comment: Has this changed by any chance?  Where do government agencies that are not affiliated with ESRI fit into this?  They are non-commercial internal use clients of ours.

Comment: @ca0v I no longer work for esri but I don't think any of this has changed. The link from my edit is what you should use to determine if you need to pay or not:  https://developers.arcgis.com/en/terms/

Comment: Does this include the basemap use?