# Is ArcGIS JavaScript API and SDK free?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, license, pricing

I wish to integrate my .NET web Application to ArcGIS via JS Web API but the application is for commercial use and at an organizational level.

Can someone please give me an insight on:

1. available SDKs
2. Free SDKS, available if any
3. Licensing policies/costs.

Comment: What research have you done? where are you stuck? we cannot do your work for you.

Answer (score 3):

I used Google to search on "ArcGIS javascript api pricing" and on the first page found [The ArcGIS JavaScript API is now available to the public](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2008/07/09/the-arcgis-javascript-api-is-now-available-to-the-public/):

> The new ArcGIS JavaScript API and its accompanying online SDK are now
>   available  for public use. ...  Everyone can use the ArcGIS JavaScript
>   API. There is no fee for using the ArcGIS  JavaScript API or deploying
>   an application built with it.

However, that appears to be outdated.  More recently on [GeoNet](https://geonet.esri.com/thread/87259) an answer to a similar question on "trying to understand the JavaScript API licensing terms and conditions" was:

> You can get a definitive answer from your customer service rep, please
>   contact them.

Comment: Free can mean two things when it comes to software. Free as in Free speech and Free as in Free Beer. The ESRI JSAPI is the latter, and there are many limitations with using it. Since I am not a lawyer, I can't comment on OP's liabilities when she uses the JSAPI

Comment: Plus the blog post is outdated. Please have a look at http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/20276/is-the-arcgis-server-javascript-api-free-to-use?rq=1 Please note that Derek Swingley who has answered the question was an ESRI employee, so that answer is quite authoritative